# synchronise clicks and scrolls accross browser windows with different hostnames

Tags: browser

I'm looking for a tool which behaves a bit like http://www.browsersync.io/ in that I can browse in one window, and scrolls and clicks etc are mirrored in another window. However, I want to compare my stage and production sites, so I'm not comparing two browsers (would be happy to use two windows of the same browser), but to compare, for example

stage.mysite.com
with
www.mysite.com

Does such a tool exist?